# How to call POST method in node.js service?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to validate my json with a jsonschema. This is my server.js code:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //the code hits this point!
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = data;

    });
    console.log(data);
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

The routes.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/api/postding',  function (req, res) {
            //do some schema validation
        var test=1;
    })
}
```

When I post invalid json I get this error now:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.parse (native)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (c:\nodestuff\trystuff\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:88:17)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at c:\nodestuff\trystuff\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:108:18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (c:\nodestuff\trystuff\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:233:14)
                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (c:\nodestuff\trystuff\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:279:7)
                    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
                        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
                            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _stream_readable.js:943:16
                                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

The question is really how can I perform a jsonschema validation for my postrequest?

Comment: Try moving `app.use(bodyParser.json());` right below `var methodoverride...`

Comment: Why are you reading in the entire raw request instead of letting `bodyParser.json()` handle the request data?

Comment: I would like to receive the raw request so I can perform a jsonschema validation in my post method

Comment: @BidhanA I tried but no dice.

Comment: I tried your code, I put console.log inside the routes.js....your http://localhost:8080/api/postding is working fine (check spelling mistake)......... put res.send({test:"message"}); after the line var test=1; which will give response to the client

Comment: ok noted when I post invalid json I get an error see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server.js

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //the code hits this point!
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
    console.log(data);
});
app.use(methodOverride());
// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

route.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/api/postding',  function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.rawBody);
        res.send({"test":"data"});
    })
}
```

which is working my pc

When I post {"name:"hoer"} through REST Client, The console output is

```
App listening on port 8080

{}
{"name:"hoer"}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Use where exactly?

Comment: See my working code the same code, actually you can put the app.use() in any order that don't matter

Comment: now try to post this invalid json: {"name:"hoer"}. What happens now?

Comment: I have added console.log(req.rawBody); inside the router.js, check my edit and output. May be you try to delete the "node_modules" folder locally and install the express, body-parser, method-override without using -g

Comment: it is working now I passed in a application/json header which I removed now!